# Subquery result into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

for example I have two table like this :

```
Table Parent
+===========+==============+
| FirstName | (PK)LastName |
+===========+==============+
| Bob       | Newbie       |
| Bella     | Goth         |
+===========+==============+

Table Child
+===========+==============+
| FirstName | (FK)LastName |
+===========+==============+
| Cassandra | Goth         |
| Cindy     | Newbie       |
| Mortimer  | Goth         |
+===========+==============+
```

what should I do to have a SELECT result like this :

```
+========+============+=====================+
| Family | ParentName | ChildName           |
+========+============+=====================+
| Goth   | Bella      | Cassandra, Mortimer |
| Newbie | Bob        | Cindy               |
+========+============+=====================+
```

what I've tried so far

```
SELECT
    A.LastName Family,
    A.FirstName ParentName,
    (
        SELECT
            COALESCE(B.FirstName + ',' , '') + B.FirstName
        FROM
            Child B
        WHERE
            B.LastName = A.LastName
    ) ChildName
FROM
    Parent A
ORDER BY
    Family ASC
```

but when I execute it shows

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way here is to use some `XML` trick:

```
select *, STUFF((SELECT ',' + FirstName 
                 FROM child where LastName = p.LastName 
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
from parent p
```

Comment: **LIFE SAVER**, could you explain why the first character of commas is deleted?

Comment: @rizkynggakool, stuff function replaces characters from position 1 of length 1 with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use subquery in this case, just a inner join.
Try to use something like that:

```
SELECT
    A.LastName Family,
    A.FirstName ParentName,
    COALESCE(B.FirstName + ',' , '') + B.FirstName    ChildName
FROM
    Parent A
    INNER JOIN Child B on A.LastName = B.LastName
ORDER BY
    A.Family ASC
```

Comment: This will not scale if someone has 3 or more children?